# Block Cipher Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, block, masking, block-cipher

Can somebody provide me a good Block Cipher Algorithm with example. This is required for Data Masking of Strings. Algorithm should be fast and not easily reversible as this will be applied on millions of records.

Either wise you can also suggest some other algorithm for fixed length Data masking algorithm which will be fast and not easily reversible.

Answer (score 0):

Use AES , it is a standard, proven secure and has libraries widely available. It should also be quite fast.

Comment: I would like to note that AES is not __proven__ to be secure, there's just a ton of smart people all around the world that tried to break it, and failed. Irrelevant for the question - just nitpicking :)

Comment: ah yes, proven as in proven technology, not as in mathematics.